# SSIS/SSDT plugin for Visual Studio 2017 - SharePoint Adapters

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

I have installed Sql Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017 and noticed that there are no SharePoint connections in the SSIS toolbox. I know I can read from a SharePoint list using the ADO connecter and save it off somewhere, but what **I'm looking for is reading a file in, a csv file, and then being able to write that information into a SharePoint list**. This is a work machine and so **I can't use the CodePlex archive options or the Kingswaysoft adapters**. I was wondering is the SharePoint adapters only a third party option or is there an out of the box solution within the SSIS options that I'm missing. I've got Visual Studio 2017 Professional as well as Sql Server Management Studio 2014. The Sql Server Data Tools are for Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sharepoint Data Flow Components

I don't think there is an official Destination Component for Sharepoint in SSIS. Since you are using SQL Server 2014, you can benefit from ODATA Source component to connect to Sharepoint. These components are found in the [SQL Server 2014 feature pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-and-uninstall-odata-source-component?view=sql-server-2014).

Unfortunately, if you need to write to a Sharepoint list, you have to use a third party components such as :

- [SSIS Data Flow Source & Destination for OData](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.SSISDataFlowSourceDestinationforOData)
- [OData SSIS Components](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/odata/ssis/)
- [Using SSIS to Automatically Populate a SharePoint List](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2763/using-ssis-to-automatically-populate-a-sharepoint-list/)
- [COZYROC - SharePoint Destination](https://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/sharepoint-destination)
- [SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft SharePoint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KingswaySoft.SSISIntegrationToolkitforMicrosoftSharePoint)

## Workarounds

You can use a Flat File Destination to Store the result inside a flat file on local folder. Then you can add a `Script Task` that will be executed after the `Data Flow Task`. Then write a C# / VB.NET script to upload the file to Sharepoint using `Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll` assembly. You can refer to the following links for more information:

- [How to: Upload a File to a SharePoint Site from a Local Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms454491(v%3Doffice.14))

Another thing to try, if you are not familiar with Script Task and you have a knowledge in Web Services, try to create a WebService to upload files to SHarepoint List and use a Web Service Task instead of Script Task:

- [Upload a Document to the SharePoint Document Library using a Webservice](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=297)
- [Upload document from Local Machine to SharePoint Library using WebService](http://www.ktskumar.com/2009/03/upload-document-from-local-machine-to-sharepoint-library/)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll take a look at this over the weekend and see what I can get setup for next week.